# check multiple ng-model values to change the caption of the button

Tags: angularjs

i need to change the caption of the button based on the value of multiple model values. i have a button. when the model values are null, it should display "Load" and if not then "refresh". If i check with one model value it works fine. How do i check entire model values.

```
<button id="load" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="float:right" > {{processState.widgetInstance.configuration.application ? 'Refresh':'Load'}}</button>

<ul>
                <li>Application:
                    <select name="application" required ng-model="processState.widgetInstance.configuration.application"  ng-options="app.APP_ID as app.APP_NAME for app in applications">

                    </select>
                </li>
                <li>Namespace:
                    <select name="namespace" required ng-model="processState.widgetInstance.configuration.namespace" ng-options="namespace.NAMESPACE_ID as namespace.NAMESPACE for namespace in namespace">

                    </select>
                </li>

              </ul>
```

In this case, if the select combo has values, it should display refresh else load. the values for the scope variables are populated from a service in this case.

Plunker 
[Working Copy](http://plnkr.co/edit/80IZzJ4ATafRtxHpswDd?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use parenthesis and `&&` operator

```js
angular.module("app",[]).controller("ctrl", function($scope){
     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<button id="load" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="float:right" > {{(application && namespace) ? 'Refresh':'Load'}}</button>

<ul>
                <li>Application:
                    <input ng-model="application" type="text"/>
                </li>
                <li>Namespace:
                      <input ng-model="namespace" type="text"/>
                </li>

              </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use angular form validation http://plnkr.co/edit/UZIqF2qG4UyNdbH4NSHu?p=preview

```
  <button id="load" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="float:right"> {{ myform.$valid ? 'Refresh': 'Load' }}</button>
  <form name='myform'>
    <ul>
      <li>Application:
        <select name="application" required ng-model="processState.widgetInstance.configuration.application" ng-options="app.APP_ID as app.APP_NAME for app in applications">

        </select>
      </li>
      <li>Namespace:
        <select name="namespace" required ng-model="processState.widgetInstance.configuration.namespace" ng-options="namespace.NAMESPACE_ID as namespace.NAMESPACE for namespace in namespace">

        </select>
      </li>

      <li>Products:
        <select name="product" required ng-model="processState.widgetInstance.configuration.product" ng-options="product.PRODUCT_ID as product.PRODUCT_NAME for product in product">

        </select>
      </li>


    </ul>
  </form>
```